# Localize A linked List of Strings Android

Tags: android, localization, translate

Hi I have a Linked List with string from my string.xml file and I have a string-en.xml file and I run the following code in my main activity in order to set the language of my app from Greek to English but the strings existing in Linked List aren't translated

```
//code running in my Main Activity
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    onCreate(null);

public class Question extends Activity {

AdView mAdView;
Random r = new Random();
String name;
int rand1 ;
int rand2;
String gender;
ConstraintLayout cl;
String q;
TextView question;
Player g = (Player) getApplication();


///lvl 3
public LinkedList<Quest> MaleList = new LinkedList<Quest>();
public LinkedList<Quest> FemaleList = new LinkedList<Quest>();

//lvl2
public LinkedList<Quest> Male2List = new LinkedList<Quest>();
public LinkedList<Quest> Female2List = new LinkedList<Quest>();

//lvl1
public LinkedList<Quest> Male1List = new LinkedList<Quest>();
public LinkedList<Quest> Female1List = new LinkedList<Quest>();

public LinkedList<Quest> TMaleList = new LinkedList<Quest>();
public LinkedList<Quest> TFemaleList = new LinkedList<Quest>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    AddTruthQuestions();
    AddDareQuestions();
}
private void AddTruthQuestions()
{

    TMaleList.add(new Quest(getString(R.string.TMale4)));
}

private void AddDareQuestions()
{
    FemaleList.add(new Quest(getString(R.string.Female1)));
    FemaleList.add(new Quest(getString(R.string.Female2)));


}       
}
```